# How to get a value from an active li > a using Jquery from Mapbox API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, html-lists, mapbox

I am trying to get the value from a forward geocoder that predicts addresses when someone is typing, and send that value to a form with the id "pickup".  I can't seem to capture the li > a from the mapbox api that becomes active when someone starts typing in the input.

Here is a screenshot of the Mapbox address search:

[image]

Snippet of code I'm trying. I've also tried many variations of this:

```
$("ul.suggestions").find("li.active").click(function() {
    pickupLoc = $(this).attr("value");
    $("#pickup")[0].value= pickupLoc; 
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share code, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I avoided trying to access the active li all together and just pulled the final address text after the user selected them using the document query selector and .value.  The mapbox-directions-origin-input ID is added here because there is a origin and destination input field.  This one selects the origin input:

```
function myFunction() {
  let origin = document.getElementById("mapbox-directions-origin- 
  input").querySelector(".mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder 
  input").value;

  document.getElementById("pickup").value = origin; 
  };
```

Comment: If this is what worked, then your problem was that your original code tried getting the value of the li, when this code shows you getting the value of the input. Also, this JavaScript references a bunch of elements that you never included in your question. People can’t help you if you don’t give the full picture.

Comment: You added the origin, destination, pickup, and dropoff ids to your answer, all of which were not defined in your original question. That’s all I’m saying. And you never actually showed us how the li gets its content, to be able to determine if there’s a better way to all of this. My main point is that jQuery is not your problem. Anything you did in vanilla js, you could have done in jQuery. For example, your original code tried to the the “value” of the li, but really you wanted the text() as someone else said.

Answer (score 3):

There is no *value* attribute of *li* element. Try `text()` instead.

Change

```
pickupLoc = $(this).attr("value");
```

To

```
pickupLoc = $(this).text();
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("ul.suggestions").find("li.active").click(function(){
  var pickupLoc = $(this).text();
  console.log(pickupLoc);
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="suggestions">
  <li class="active">
    <a>
      <strong>ABC</strong>
      Sample Text 1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>
      <strong>SDF</strong>
      Sample Text 2
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```